# Jquery animate positon function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I don't know english.
I want to call the function in seconds of its animation

Example : start animate call 0,5 second repeat call function.

```
$("#image").animate({ top: '582px'}, startEffectTime1);
// call 0,5 second function
```

Comment: So, you want this to be called every 0.5 seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [step in Jquery animate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918744/step-in-jquery-animate-function)

Comment: yes 0,5 secound call other function